# speech recognition -NSSpeechRecognizer or other?

Tags: objective-c

I have read the Apple docs for the `NSSpeechRecognizer`, and i still called `openears` .

Apple say this :

```
The NSSpeechRecognizer class is the Cocoa interface to Speech Recognition on OS X. Speech Recognition is architected as a “command and control” voice recognition system. It uses a finite state grammar and listens for phrases in that grammar. When it recognizes a phrase, it notifies the client process. This architecture is different from that used to support dictation.
```

I could not understand what practically does it means .
We need to listen to the user on the iPhone when button is hitted , and than recognize words and numbers that spoken.
Recognition should be as along as user speaks ,than when stopped, it returned the word/words.
We don't want it to stop in the middle like: 3 hundred ->will not return 3 ..but wait till silence.

Does OpenEar is better or the Apple native one ?

Thanks .

Comment: Apple native isn't available for iPhone, so you have to use open ears, nuance dragon, ispeech or any other framework

Comment: oh i didn't see that. thanks a lot . does open ears good for my requirement ?

Comment: I have just used ispeech and does what you need, but you can try all of them.